# query_posts doesn't order by title

Tags: query-posts, title, order

It seems like stupid bug, but how can i order by title? It anyways orders by date! I'm using:

```
query_posts( array( 
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
) );
```

I want to use this in function as SHORTCODE. What i'm trying to achieve is to create site map / index of all entries in alphabetic order.
Also i'm using newest WP.

Comment: Can we see a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` of the generated query? Also, a bit of context for this code would be helpful. Are you modifying the main loop query, or running a secondary loop?

Comment: i created function which works as shortcode, it displays all entries like Index, let's say it shows letter and after letter all entries who starts with that leter, like site map. I'll post you array in Question.

Comment: Well array looked HUGE and it was ordered by date, so i decided not to post it here. I'm not new to php or wordpress so i don't think that i'm missing somehing in code. I posted you simple version of my function.

Comment: You're using this as a **SHORTCODE**? Meaning you're executing it *inside the **post content***?

Comment: Yes, but i'm using shortcode in page, also my content is empty, only shortcode, anyway, so what can i do? should i make template and avoid shortcode? Also i think it should reset the query and make new one with mine..so where the problem? i'm confused

Comment: A page *is* a post. That will make no difference whatsoever. There is so much wrong with this approach, that I don't even know where to begin, really. What is it, ultimately, that you're trying to accomplish? We will probably need to re-write the question accordingly, in order to answer it properly.

Comment: as i said i want to make alphabetic list of all posts (my selected post type, in this case page is for example). So visitors in one page can see all entries like book's index. But i understood that i have to use SQL than, instead of post query, thanks for help, i'll try new aprouch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Chip Bennett who told me that i'm doing wrong by using `query_posts` inside content. So i used `get_posts` and i got what i wanted, thanks!

Here is sample of how can you do it, if you got the same problem as me:

```
function some_name(){

global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'post_type'=>'page', 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

         if ( !empty($myposts) ) {
              foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
              the_title();
              echo '<br>';             

              endforeach;

         } 

          $post = $tmp_post;

 }
```

Comment: If you'll add the actual code you used to solve your question, I'll gladly up-vote.

Answer (score -1):

Another post has this code inside a function, but for those looking to simply add alphabetized posts to a custom theme, for example, you can use the following...

```
<?php // Alphabetize posts from the *** category
global $post;
$temp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'category' => *categoryID*, 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$these_posts = get_posts( $args );

if( !empty($these_posts) ) {
    foreach( $these_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
?>

<?php 

/* HTML/PHP code goes here to display each post */

the_title("<h2>", "</h2>");
the_content("<div class='content'>", "</div>"); 

?>

<?php 
    endforeach; // End of The Loop.
}
$post = $temp_post;
?>
```