# Wp query orderby 'title' doesn't work

Tags: wp-query, order, title

I would like to order a list of post title alphabetically. 
I am using this specific query

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'category_name'     => 'reportage',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'orderby'           => 'title',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<ul><li style="float:left; width:100%;"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" style="color:#D34D3D">'.get_the_title().'</a></li></ul>';
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The query worked perfect until a certain point of the list where the order seems to be messed up.

Why the order doesn't work correctly for all the post title?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work correctly? Do you have an example? Wrong db collation?

Comment: Sure, you can see the example on this page: http://www.camillabaresani.com/dev/i-miei-articoli/interviste/alessandro-borghi-il-vichingo-della-garbatella/

Comment: most likely it is working properly.... without knowing what is your data set it is impossible to say anything more intelligent.

Comment: show this link
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54347/query-posts-doesnt-order-by-title

Comment: In your link "Sommario" is perfect display title in ASC orde then what is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem and could not figure it out.  Eventually found the problem when I took a look at the custom post type entries in the database and noticed that the results that were out of order had values set in the menu_order column.  After a bit of digging I realised that it was the Post Types Order plugin that was set to auto and 'injecting' an additional parameter to the orderby parameter.  I understand you can turn off the auto function in the plugin settings but I opted to do it via the query parameters:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'my-custom-post-type', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'ignore_custom_sort' => true
    )  
);
```

And BINGO! the results came back in the correct order.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: So true! When the 'Post Types Order'-plugin is set to autopilot you can easily forget about it and despair... Thanks a lot, philip!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `'suppress_filters' => true` to your query args. Maybe you have a plugin that modifies the queries.

You could also check if the posts out of order (the first one) is a sticky post. Sticky posts by default skip the order queue.

You can disable this by adding `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` to your query args.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added  the string, however it doesn't work. I tried to deactivate CPO (Custom Post Order) in order to make the default order, without results. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is $args, do this:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name'     => 'reportage',
    'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'ASC' )
);
```

You can also order by multiple parameters, like:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name'     => 'reportage',
    'orderby' => array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC', 'post_date' => 'DESC' ),
);
```

Comment: This seemed to fix my ordering issue. It's nonsensical that this format works but the default 'order' and 'order_by' args do not. But, c'est la vie.